# Google map doesn't appear and markers don't generate from xml file

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps

The initMap function worked until I added the downloadurl function, and now nothing's appearing on the screen. Everthing else on the page works normally. How can I generate the map and also the coordinates with their respective markers?

```
function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 45.75372, lng: 21.22571},
zoom: 15
});


function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
   new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
   new XMLHttpRequest;

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (request.readyState == 4) {
   request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
   callback(request, request.status);
 }
 };

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}


downloadUrl('map.php', function(data) {
  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
    var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
    var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
    var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
    var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

    var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
    var strong = document.createElement('strong');
    strong.textContent = name
    infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
    infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

    var text = document.createElement('text');
    text.textContent = address
    infowincontent.appendChild(text);
    var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      label: icon.label
    });
```

Below is the php that generates the xml. This works as expected.

```
    <?php 
     include('includes/functions.php');
     function parseToXML($htmlStr)
     {
              $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
              $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
              $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
              $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
              $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
              return $xmlStr;
          }
          $res = getMarkers();
          header("Content-type: text/xml");
          echo '<markers>';
          while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo '<marker ';
            echo 'id="' . $row['id'] . '" ';
            echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
            echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
            echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
            echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
            echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
            echo '/>';
          }
          echo '</markers>';

          ?>
```

Comment: What JavaScript errors do you get?  The posted code is not complete.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Either you didn't paste ALL of the `downloadUrl` code or you have an error and it will not be sending the ajax request - there are closing braces missing from the end of the function definition. Also, the callback function is truing to create `text` element?? No such element afaik

Answer (score 0):

I started off formatting your original code and found that there are bits missing and ended up with what you see below which, for the record, has not been tested at all. If the code you originally posted was "as is" ( ie: complete ) then there would have been numerous errors in the console I suspect. I interpreted the above code almost as written - in that the `initMap` function itself defines the methods that it uses as opposed to them being separate - whether or not the original code was written in that manner is not clear due to the formatting of the question.

```
function initMap() {
    var mkrs=evts=[];

    var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 45.75372,
            lng: 21.22571
        },
        zoom: 15
    });
    var iWin=new google.maps.InfoWindow( { maxWidth:400 } );


    var downloadUrl=function(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if( request.status==200 && request.readyState == 4 ) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback.call( this, request, request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type') );
            }
        };
        request.open( 'GET', url, true );
        request.send( null );
    }

    var callback=function( data, ctype ) {
        /* inspect response - if there is none then panic! */
        console.log( 'Response: %o, Content-Type: %s', data, ctype );
        /*
            I'd be tempted to fork the logic in the php code
            so that if there is an error/exception of some type
            then send a non xml content type response and use the 
            ctype here to stop processing client side...
        */
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');

        Array.prototype.forEach.call( markers, function( node ) {

            var id = node.getAttribute('id');
            var name = node.getAttribute('name');
            var address = node.getAttribute('address');
            var type = node.getAttribute('type');

            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat( node.getAttribute('lat') ),
                parseFloat( node.getAttribute('lng') )
            );

            /* prepare infowindow content */
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            var strong = document.createElement('strong');
                strong.textdiv = name;
            var text = document.createElement('p');
                text.textdiv = address;


            div.appendChild( strong );
            div.appendChild( document.createElement('br') );                    
            div.appendChild( text );


            var icon = customLabel[ type ] || {};   /* ? where is customLabel defined ? */
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                id:id,
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
            });
            mkrs.push( marker );


            var evt = google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function( event ){
                iWin.setdiv( div );
                iWin.open( map, marker );
                iWin.setPosition( event.latLng );
            });
            evts.push( evt );
        });
    }

    downloadUrl.call( this, 'map.php', callback );
}
```